# Is it possible to not make use of `next/Image` in my Next JS app, It gives lot and lot of troubles rather than solve problems for me

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js13

Width property expected integer value in pixels, I fixed the bug though, But I have many more Image tags to go through. Trying to get the proper sizing for mobile and desktop

I looked at the docs, if their was a less redundant approach, I didn't find any

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the Next-specific `Image` component you can always manually use the native `img` and `picture` elements available in HTML.